# Does this logical form analysis is correct

Tags: logic

I ended up with this solution :

If P(x) stands for "x is a prime number", then :
$$ x,y \in \{ w, z \in N | (P(w) \lor P(z) \land \lnot(P(w) \land P(z)) \}$$
to: "x and y are natural numbers, and exactly one of them is prime". However it seems correct for me, it might be not the case. If it's not correct, please point me to the right direction to learn how to solve such problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close. We say "The pair $(x,y)$ is an element of the set of pairs of natural numbers where exactly one member of the pair is prime," by:

$$(x,y)\in\{(w,z)\in\Bbb N^2: (P(w)\vee P(z))\wedge\neg (P(w)\wedge P(z))\}$$

Or you could just say "$(x,y)$ is a pair of natural numbers and exactly one of them is prime." $$(x,y)\in\Bbb N^2\,\wedge\, (P(x)\lor P(y))\,\land\,\lnot(P(x)\land P(y))$$

Comment: Oops, you beat me to it!

Comment: Thanks guys, I started the "How to prove it" book. So there will be a lot of questions on the topic (no previous experience in this direction) . @Graham Kemp: Could you please explain me some of the notation you used? The " : " and why the set of natural numbers symbol is like "squared" ? Thanks.